# making Django DeleteView generic?

Tags: python, django

I am using the `django DeleteView` class to delete different entries. The only thing that differs from call to call is the model attribute. It there anyway to have only one call for delete for different models? My suggestion is something along these lines but I don't know how to implement it. Any suggestions?

`views.py`:

```
class Delete(DeleteView):

    template_name='kammem/delete.html'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('forl')
    model=super().get_context_data()

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
  
         mod=self.kwargs['model']        
         if mod=='forening':
             model=forening
         elif mod=='person'

 return model
```

`urls.py`:

```
 path('delete/<int:pk>/<str:model>',Delete.as_view(),name='delete'),
```

Comment: You could write a view to delete models based on the model name in the path. I wonder how many models you have for this to be preferable to writing a DeleteView for each. As you application becomes more complex, you might start to regret having one class handling so many code paths.

Comment: If you haven't already seen this, it may be helpful in working out what to inherit from: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/

Comment: that the thing, instead of writing a lot of delete views that only differ in the model name, I want to pass the model name in the url and then pass the right one in the delete view. i.e one delete view instead of a lot of them.

Comment: It's late where I am so I'm not going to write this for you. One tip I can give you is that you can use this function instead of an if-else block: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model

Comment: Or this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model

Comment: Although you'd need to be careful not to expose models you wouldn't want a user to delete.